# Why there are three unexpected worker threads when a Win32 console application starts up?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Here is the screenshot of the situation!

[image: Here is the screenshot!]

I created a Visual C++ Win32 Console Application with VS2010. When I started the application, I found that there were four threads: one 'Main Thread' and three worker threads (I didn't write any code).

I don't know where these three worker threads came from.
I would like to know the role of these three threads.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 49):

Windows 10 implemented a new way of loading DLLs - several worker threads do it in parallel (`LdrpWorkCallback`). All Windows 10 processes now have several such threads.

Before Win10, the system (`ntdll.dll`) always loaded DLLs in a single thread, but starting with Win10 this behaviour changed. Now a "Parallel loader" exists in `ntdll`. Now the loading task (`NTSTATUS LdrpSnapModule(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext)`) can be executed in worker threads. Almost every DLL has imports (dependent DLLs), so when a DLL is loaded - its dependent DLLs are also loaded and this process is recursive (dependent DLLs have own dependencies).

The function `void LdrpMapAndSnapDependency(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext)` walks the current loaded DLL import table and loads its direct (1st level) dependent DLLs by calling `LdrpLoadDependentModule()` (which internally calls `LdrpMapAndSnapDependency()` for the newly loaded DLL - so this process is recursive). Finally, `LdrpMapAndSnapDependency()` needs to call `NTSTATUS LdrpSnapModule(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext)` to bind imports to the already loaded DLLs. `LdrpSnapModule()` is executed for many DLLs in the top level DLL load process, and this process is independent for every DLL - so this is a good place to parallelize. `LdrpSnapModule()` in most cases does not load new DLLs, but only binds import to export from already loaded ones. But if an import is resolved to a forwarded export (which rarely happens) - the new, forwarded DLL, is loaded.

---

*Some current implementation details:*

1. first of all, let us look into the `struct _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` new field - `ULONG LoaderThreads`. this `LoaderThreads` (if set to nonzero) enables or disables "Parallel loader" in the new process. When we create a new process by [`ZwCreateUserProcess()`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a583ed29dc52a44eb728f214655a2c1f0) - the 9th argument is
   *`PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters`*. but if we use `CreateProcess[Internal]W()` - we cannot pass `PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` directly - only `STARTUPINFO`. `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` is partially initialized from `STARTUPINFO`, but we do not control `ULONG LoaderThreads`, and it will always be zero (if we do not call `ZwCreateUserProcess()` or set a hook to this routine).
2. In the new process initialization phase, `LdrpInitializeExecutionOptions()` is called (from `LdrpInitializeProcess()`). This routine checks `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\<app name>` for several values (if the `<app name>` subkey exists - usually it doesn't), including `MaxLoaderThreads` (*`REG_DWORD`*) - if `MaxLoaderThreads` exists - its value overrides `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.LoaderThreads`.
3. `LdrpCreateLoaderEvents()` is called. This routine must create 2 global events: `HANDLE LdrpWorkCompleteEvent, LdrpLoadCompleteEvent;`, which are used for synchronization.

   ```cpp
   NTSTATUS LdrpCreateLoaderEvents()
   {
       NTSTATUS status = ZwCreateEvent(&LdrpWorkCompleteEvent, EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, 0, SynchronizationEvent, TRUE);

       if (0 <= status)
       {
           status = ZwCreateEvent(&LdrpLoadCompleteEvent, EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, 0, SynchronizationEvent, TRUE);
       }
       return status;
   }
   ```
4. `LdrpInitializeProcess()` calls `void LdrpDetectDetour()`. This name speaks for itself. it does not return a value but initializes the global variable `BOOLEAN LdrpDetourExist`. This routine first checks whether some loader critical routines are hooked - currently these are 5 routines:

   - NtOpenFile
   - NtCreateSection
   - NtQueryAttributesFile
   - NtOpenSection
   - NtMapViewOfSection

   If yes - `LdrpDetourExist = TRUE;`

   If not hooked - `ThreadDynamicCodePolicyInfo` is queried - full code:

   ```cpp
   void LdrpDetectDetour()
   {
       if (LdrpDetourExist) return ;

       static PVOID LdrpCriticalLoaderFunctions[] = {
           NtOpenFile,
           NtCreateSection,
           ZwQueryAttributesFile,
           ZwOpenSection,
           ZwMapViewOfSection,
       };

       static M128A LdrpThunkSignature[5] = {
           //***
       };

       ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(LdrpCriticalLoaderFunctions);
       M128A* ppv = (M128A*)LdrpCriticalLoaderFunctions;
       M128A* pps = LdrpThunkSignature; 
       do
       {
           if (ppv->Low != pps->Low || ppv->High != pps->High)
           {
               if (LdrpDebugFlags & 5)
               {
                   DbgPrint("!!! Detour detected, disable parallel loading\n");
                   LdrpDetourExist = TRUE;
                   return;
               }
           }

       } while (pps++, ppv++, --n);

       BOOL DynamicCodePolicy;

       if (0 <= ZwQueryInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadDynamicCodePolicyInfo, &DynamicCodePolicy, sizeof(DynamicCodePolicy), 0))
       {
           if (LdrpDetourExist = (DynamicCodePolicy == 1))
           {
               if (LdrpMapAndSnapWork)
               {
                   WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks(LdrpMapAndSnapWork, TRUE);//TpWaitForWork
                   TpReleaseWork(LdrpMapAndSnapWork);//CloseThreadpoolWork
                   LdrpMapAndSnapWork = 0;
                   TpReleasePool(LdrpThreadPool);//CloseThreadpool
                   LdrpThreadPool = 0;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. `LdrpInitializeProcess()` calls `NTSTATUS LdrpEnableParallelLoading (ULONG LoaderThreads)` - as `LdrpEnableParallelLoading(ProcessParameters->LoaderThreads)`:

   ```cpp
   NTSTATUS LdrpEnableParallelLoading (ULONG LoaderThreads)
   {
       LdrpDetectDetour();

       if (LoaderThreads)
       {
           LoaderThreads = min(LoaderThreads, 16);// not more than 16 threads allowed
           if (LoaderThreads <= 1) return STATUS_SUCCESS;
       }
       else
       {
           if (RtlGetSuiteMask() & 0x10000) return STATUS_SUCCESS; 
           LoaderThreads = 4;// default for 4 threads
       }

       if (LdrpDetourExist) return STATUS_SUCCESS;

       NTSTATUS status = TpAllocPool(&LdrpThreadPool, 1);//CreateThreadpool

       if (0 <= status)
       {
           TpSetPoolWorkerThreadIdleTimeout(LdrpThreadPool, -300000000);// 30 second idle timeout
           TpSetPoolMaxThreads(LdrpThreadPool, LoaderThreads - 1);//SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum 
           TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON CallbackEnviron = { };
           CallbackEnviron->CallbackPriority = TP_CALLBACK_PRIORITY_NORMAL;
           CallbackEnviron->Size = sizeof(TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON);
           CallbackEnviron->Pool = LdrpThreadPool;
           CallbackEnviron->Version = 3;

           status = TpAllocWork(&LdrpMapAndSnapWork, LdrpWorkCallback, 0, &CallbackEnviron);//CreateThreadpoolWork
       }

       return status;
   }
   ```

   A special loader thread pool is created - `LdrpThreadPool`, with `LoaderThreads - 1` max threads. Idle timeout is set to 30 seconds (after which the thread exits) and allocated `PTP_WORK LdrpMapAndSnapWork`, which is then used in `void LdrpQueueWork(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext)`.
6. Global variables used by the parallel loader:

   ```cpp
   HANDLE LdrpWorkCompleteEvent, LdrpLoadCompleteEvent;
   CRITICAL_SECTION LdrpWorkQueueLock;
   LIST_ENTRY LdrpWorkQueue = { &LdrpWorkQueue, &LdrpWorkQueue };


   ULONG LdrpWorkInProgress;
   BOOLEAN LdrpDetourExist;
   PTP_POOL LdrpThreadPool;

   PTP_WORK LdrpMapAndSnapWork;

   enum DRAIN_TASK {
       WaitLoadComplete, WaitWorkComplete
   };

   struct LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT
   {
       UNICODE_STRING BaseDllName;
       PVOID somestruct;
       ULONG Flags;//some unknown flags
       NTSTATUS* pstatus; //final status of load
       _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* ParentEntry; // of 'parent' loading dll
       _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* Entry; // this == Entry->LoadContext
       LIST_ENTRY WorkQueueListEntry;
       _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* ReplacedEntry;
       _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY** pvImports;// in same ordef as in IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR piid
       ULONG ImportDllCount;// count of pvImports
       LONG TaskCount;
       PVOID pvIAT;
       ULONG SizeOfIAT;
       ULONG CurrentDll; // 0 <= CurrentDll < ImportDllCount
       PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR piid;
       ULONG OriginalIATProtect;
       PVOID GuardCFCheckFunctionPointer;
       PVOID* pGuardCFCheckFunctionPointer;
   };
   ```

   *Unfortunately `LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT` is not contained in published `.pdb` files, so my definitions include only partial names*.

   ```cpp
   struct {
       ULONG MaxWorkInProgress;//4 - values from explorer.exe at some moment
       ULONG InLoaderWorker;//7a (this mean LdrpSnapModule called from worker thread)
       ULONG InLoadOwner;//87 (LdrpSnapModule called direct, in same thread as `LdrpMapAndSnapDependency`)
   } LdrpStatistics;

   // for statistics
   void LdrpUpdateStatistics()
   {
     LdrpStatistics.MaxWorkInProgress = max(LdrpStatistics.MaxWorkInProgress, LdrpWorkInProgress);
     NtCurrentTeb()->LoaderWorker ? LdrpStatistics.InLoaderWorker++ : LdrpStatistics.InLoadOwner++
   }
   ```

   In `TEB.CrossTebFlags` - now exist 2 new flags:

   ```cpp
   USHORT LoadOwner : 01; // 0x1000;
   USHORT LoaderWorker : 01; // 0x2000;
   ```

   Last 2 bits is spare (`USHORT SpareSameTebBits : 02; // 0xc000`)
7. `LdrpMapAndSnapDependency(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext)` includes the following code:

   ```cpp
   LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* Entry = LoadContext->CurEntry;
   if (LoadContext->pvIAT)
   {
       Entry->DdagNode->State = LdrModulesSnapping;
       if (LoadContext->PrevEntry)// if recursive call
       {
           LdrpQueueWork(LoadContext); // !!!
       }
       else
       {
           status = LdrpSnapModule(LoadContext);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       Entry->DdagNode->State = LdrModulesSnapped;
   }
   ```

   So, if `LoadContext->PrevEntry` (say we load `user32.dll`. In the first call to `LdrpMapAndSnapDependency()`, `LoadContext->PrevEntry` will be always 0 (when `CurEntry` points to `user32.dll`), but when we recursively call `LdrpMapAndSnapDependency()` for it dependency `gdi32.dll` - `PrevEntry` will be for `user32.dll` and `CurEntry` for `gdi32.dll`), we do not direct call `LdrpSnapModule(LoadContext);` but `LdrpQueueWork(LoadContext);`.
8. `LdrpQueueWork()` is simply:

   ```cpp
   void LdrpQueueWork(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext)
   {
       if (0 <= ctx->pstatus)
       {
           EnterCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);

           InsertHeadList(&LdrpWorkQueue, &LoadContext->WorkQueueListEntry);

           LeaveCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);

           if (LdrpMapAndSnapWork && !RtlGetCurrentPeb()->Ldr->ShutdownInProgress)
           {
               SubmitThreadpoolWork(LdrpMapAndSnapWork);//TpPostWork
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   We insert `LoadContext` to `LdrpWorkQueue` and if "Parallel loader" is started (`LdrpMapAndSnapWork != 0`) and not `ShutdownInProgress` - we submit work to loader pool. But even if the pool is not initialized (say because Detours exist) - there will be no error - we process this task in `LdrpDrainWorkQueue()`.
9. In a worker thread callback, this is executed:

   ```cpp
   void LdrpWorkCallback()
   {
       if (LdrpDetourExist) return;

       EnterCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);

       PLIST_ENTRY Entry = RemoveEntryList(&LdrpWorkQueue);

       if (Entry != &LdrpWorkQueue)
       {
           ++LdrpWorkInProgress;
           LdrpUpdateStatistics()
       }

       LeaveCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);

       if (Entry != &LdrpWorkQueue)
       {
           LdrpProcessWork(CONTAINING_RECORD(Entry, LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT, WorkQueueListEntry), FALSE);
       }
   }
   ```

   We simply popup an entry from `LdrpWorkQueue`, convert it to `LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT*` (`CONTAINING_RECORD(Entry, LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT, WorkQueueListEntry)`) and call `void LdrpProcessWork(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* LoadContext, BOOLEAN LoadOwner)`.
10. `void LdrpProcessWork(LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT* ctx, BOOLEAN LoadOwner)`
    in general calls `LdrpSnapModule(LoadContext)` and in the end the next code is executed:

    ```cpp
    if (!LoadOwner)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);
        BOOLEAN bSetEvent = --LdrpWorkInProgress == 1 && IsListEmpty(&LdrpWorkQueue);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);
        if (bSetEvent) ZwSetEvent(LdrpWorkCompleteEvent, 0);
    }
    ```

    So, if we are not `LoadOwner` (in worked thread), we decrement `LdrpWorkInProgress`, and if `LdrpWorkQueue` is empty then signal `LdrpWorkCompleteEvent` (`LoadOwner` can wait on it).
11. and finally, `LdrpDrainWorkQueue()` is called from `LoadOwner` (primary thread) to "drain" the WorkQueue. It can possible pop and directly execute tasks pushed to `LdrpWorkQueue` by `LdrpQueueWork()`, and yet is not popped by worked threads or because parallel loader is disabled (in this case `LdrpQueueWork()` also push `LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT` but not really post work to worked thread), and finally wait (if need) on `LdrpWorkCompleteEvent` or `LdrpLoadCompleteEvent` events.

    ```cpp
    enum DRAIN_TASK {
        WaitLoadComplete, WaitWorkComplete
    };

    void LdrpDrainWorkQueue(DRAIN_TASK task)
    {
        BOOLEAN LoadOwner = FALSE;

        HANDLE hEvent = task ? LdrpWorkCompleteEvent : LdrpLoadCompleteEvent;

        for(;;)
        {
            PLIST_ENTRY Entry;

            EnterCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);

            if (LdrpDetourExist && task == WaitLoadComplete)
            {
                if (!LdrpWorkInProgress)
                {
                    LdrpWorkInProgress = 1;
                    LoadOwner = TRUE;
                }
                Entry = &LdrpWorkQueue;
            }
            else
            {
                Entry = RemoveHeadList(&LdrpWorkQueue);

                if (Entry == &LdrpWorkQueue)
                {
                    if (!LdrpWorkInProgress)
                    {
                        LdrpWorkInProgress = 1;
                        LoadOwner = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!LdrpDetourExist)
                    {
                        ++LdrpWorkInProgress;
                    }
                    LdrpUpdateStatistics();
                }
            }
            LeaveCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);

            if (LoadOwner)
            {
                NtCurrentTeb()->LoadOwner = 1;
                return;
            }

            if (Entry != &LdrpWorkQueue)
            {
                LdrpProcessWork(CONTAINING_RECORD(Entry, LDRP_LOAD_CONTEXT, WorkQueueListEntry), FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                ZwWaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    ```
12. ```cpp
    void LdrpDropLastInProgressCount()
    {
      NtCurrentTeb()->LoadOwner = 0;
      EnterCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);
      LdrpWorkInProgress = 0;
      LeaveCriticalSection(&LdrpWorkQueueLock);
      ZwSetEvent(LdrpLoadCompleteEvent);
    }
    ```

Comment: This seems like it could be a helpful answer if it were organized.

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, i research "parallel loader" implementation several month ago and have much more data with code snippets. but unfortunately i have too pure english to describe this and not sure - are this is interesting to somebody at all. in shorter words - now exist special working pool of threads, which ntdll  used for load dlls. so absolute normal +2/3 working thread in every process (however this threads exit if 30+ seconds no more dll loaded in process)

Comment: FWIW, the `RtlGetSuiteMask() & 0x10000` condition appears to be something related to Windows Phone.