# Why would a process hang within RtlExitUserProcess/LdrpDrainWorkQueue?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process

To debug a locked file problem, we're calling SysInternal's Handle64.exe 4.11 from a .NET process (via `Process.Start` with asynchronous output redirection). The calling process hangs on `Process.WaitForExit` because the Handle64 process doesn't exit (for more than two hours).

We took a dump of the corresponding Handle64 process and checked it in the Visual Studio 2017 debugger. It shows two threads ("Main Thread" and "ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread").

Main thread's call stack:

> ```
> ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject ()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpDrainWorkQueue()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess()  Unknown
> kernel32.dll!ExitProcessImplementation  ()  Unknown
> handle64.exe!000000014000664c() Unknown
> handle64.exe!00000001400082a5() Unknown
> kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk    ()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart    ()  Unknown
> ```

Worker thread's call stack:

> ```
> ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()   Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpDrainWorkQueue()  Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeThread()    Unknown
> ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitialize() Unknown
> ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk()  Unknown
> ```

My question is: Why would a process hang in `LdrpDrainWorkQueue`? From https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789684/62838, I gather that this is the Windows 10 parallel loader at work, but why would it get stuck while exiting the process? Can this be caused by how we invoke Handle64 from another process? I.e., are we doing something wrong or is this rather a bug in Handle64?

Comment: are this is only 1 worker thread in handle64 ? i guess that more and with different call stacks. are this hung is always on your system or random ?

Comment: i even can say that this is callstack not of `LoaderWorker` thread - it never call `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` from `LdrpInitializeThread` because this threads have special, very light initializations

Comment: what i can say - at time when `ExitProcess` called - some *DLL* is loaded in another thread, the call-stack of worked thread - this is 100% not loader worker thread, but some another. both, main and this new thread which only just begin execute (at very early stage) wait on `LdrpLoadCompleteEvent` event. this event is set in single place `LdrpDropLastInProgressCount`, when load of some *DLL* complete. must be additional treads in process. here need more look in debugger. as side note, easy possible not use handle64 at all, but get all info yourself

Comment: @RbMm Thanks a lot for the analysis! According to the debugger there was only that one worker thread in Handle64.exe when the dump was taken. (Maybe the other threads have already exited?)

Comment: It doesn't occur always, we've seen it only once so far in a few dozens of calls.

Comment: "as side note, easy possible not use handle64 at all, but get all info yourself" - well, we're not really system programmers, and this instrumentation was only added to diagnose another problem, so it would probably be a lot of effort and complexity for us to implement handle inspection ourselves, wouldn't it?

Comment: you say that only 2 threads in process at this point ? very strange. interesting of course look for this under debugger, but problem catch such situation. enumerate handles in system, get info about it, etc - very simply task. here only problem if you need handles from protected processes - here need driver support (handle64 use *PROCEXP152.SYS*) *diagnose another problem* - what problem ?

Comment: "what problem?" - in our system, deleting files programmatically sometimes doesn't work due to different errors (cannot delete a directory because a file is in use, cannot delete a directory because it isn't empty, cannot create a file due to unauthorized access), but it works if retried a few seconds later. We suspected some other process might be locking them, so we tried to invoke Handl64.exe as a quick way of determining if that was the case. But this is probably a topic for another question :)

Comment: for concrete file you need use not Handl64.exe but [`FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class)

Comment: anyway, not related to your real problem, interesting will be catch some hung and research it

Answer (score 1):

How long did you wait?

According to [this analysis](https://threatvector.cylance.com/en_us/home/windows-10-parallel-loading-breakdown.html),

> The worker thread idle timeout is set to 30 seconds. Programs which
>   execute in less than 30 seconds will appear to hang due to
>   ntdll!TppWorkerThread waiting for the idle timeout before the process
>   terminates.

I would recommend trying to set the registry key specified in that article to disable the parallel loader and see if this resolved the issue.

```
Parent Key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\handle64.exe
Value Name: MaxLoaderThreads
Type: DWORD
Value: 1 to disable
```

Comment: We waited for more than 2 hours, I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: We can't currently reliably reproduce this issue (it only occurred once in a few hundred calls so far), so disabling parallel loading to see if it resolves the issue is difficult.

Comment: Without easy reproducibility, I would be tempted to just add a timeout to your `WaitForExit` and just give up on that process and try running it again. I think it unlikely you'll find anyone on SO who will be able to help you fix it. Good luck!

Comment: *Programs which execute in less than 30 seconds will appear to hang* this of course not true. worked thread run itself - not lead to hung. it not hold any "critical section" (in wide sense). if simply exit thread without call `ExitProcess` process of course not exit until this worker threads not exit, but this is not hung. and if we call `ExitProcess` - we normal exit

Comment: @DarkFalcon "I would be tempted to just add a timeout to your WaitForExit" - That's exactly what we've done - this question is mostly for understanding the problem better. :)