# Why I have multiple threads created at launch of my program?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I realized by doing a simple multithreading program that multiple threads were created at the start of my program.

I saw that Windows 10 used a parallel loader of dll which created me 4 threads: 3 of ntdll.dll and one of Win32. Using the thread.h library of C++ 11 and creating one worker thread and using the `thread::hardware_concurrency()` command, I would have liked to have 2 threads, the main thread and the worker thread.

Can I disable parallel loading?

Comment: disabling is described in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789199/why-there-are-three-unexpected-worker-threads-when-a-win32-console-application-s   but in general there's also a bunch of other drivers that like to inject threads into your process. For example GPU drivers often inject multiple threads into processes using the gpu