# How to Fast Fail a single threaded application with Windows 10 Parallel Loading?

Tags: windows, process, windows-kernel

I have a utility application to spawn (or respawn) other processes, set up the console window and its title and icon and connect the standard handles to file-like objects (file, named pipe, socket).

In case of any failure this application has to terminate immediately and as fast as possible.

```
if ( !success )
  ExitProcess( 1 );
```

Problems come with "Window 10 parallel library loading support in ntdll.dll".

As [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789199/why-there-are-three-unexpected-worker-threads-when-a-win32-console-application-s/42789684#42789684) and [in this article](https://threatvector.cylance.com/en_us/home/windows-10-parallel-loading-breakdown.html) this feature prevents the fast fail.

> Programs which execute in less than 30 seconds will appear to hang due to ntdll!TppWorkerThreadwaiting for the idle timeout before the process terminates.

[image]

[image]

Even if I set MaxLoaderThreads in the Registry, the tread pool is created when I call [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw).

[image: image: MaxLoaderThreads in Registry]

My Question is, how to terminate the process without waiting for the loader-threads, without calling [ZwCreateUserProcess](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a583ed29dc52a44eb728f214655a2c1f0) directly and without modifying the Registry on the target machine.

My idea is to have a replacement for [ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) which calls [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) as follows (and it seems to work).

```
VOID WINAPI ExitProcessNow( UINT uExitCode )
{
  if ( TerminateProcess( GetCurrentProcess(),
                         uExitCode ) )
    ExitThread( uExitCode );
  else
    ExitProcess( uExitCode );
}
```

---

**EDIT** Some clarification

Assume the following program:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#ifndef _DEBUG
#pragma comment ( linker, "/ENTRY:EntryPoint" )
#else
#define EntryPoint main
#endif

#define NUMBER_OF_WORKER_THREADS  3

DWORD __stdcall WorkerThreadProc( PVOID __unused )
{
  for ( ;; )
    Sleep( 1000 );
}

void EntryPoint()
{
  for ( int ii = NUMBER_OF_WORKER_THREADS; ii; --ii )
    CloseHandle( CreateThread( NULL, 0, WorkerThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL ) );
  Sleep( 10000 );
  // For demonstration do not call ExitProcess.
  // ExitProcess( 0 );
}
```

The initial thread starts three workers, waits 10 seconds and then exits. The workers are running indefinitely.
If `_DEBUG` is not defined, there is no CRT code which calls ExitProcess at the end of `main()` and the process continues running with three threads at WorkerThreadProc.

This was the situation I observed. My process and/or a spawned process where running with three threads with an entry point at `ntdll!Tp...`.

My code definitively called `ExitProcess` (after replacing `ExitProcess` by `TerminateProcess` it worked).

The point is, in cases when the program has to exit it has to exit immediately, independent of any locks in any library or any thread. Maybe it has something to do with the parallel loading or not, maybe there is as deadlock in my or the spawned code, it doesn't matter. The program has to exit and the process has to become signaled.

The main use case of this program is to respawn other programs when they exit for any reason as [/sbin/init](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/sysvinit-core/init.8.en.html) does when configured with `respawn` in [/etc/inittab](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/sysvinit-core/inittab.5.en.html).

Comment: if you call `ExitProcess` - process exit **just**. parallel library loading of course not affect this. your quote related to case when `ExitProcess` **not called**. so you go in **wrong direction**. you not need any replacement for `ExitProcess`. problem in something else

Comment: Sometimes processes hang around after ending the program (also e.g. Excel) and I see threads at ntdll.dll!TpReleaseWork. Maybe this is a bug or happens in unexpected conditions, but it happens. To work around this situation I'll use TerminateProcess() to kill myself in a fast-fail-condition.

Comment: in what your question at all ? absolute unclear. and how here parallel loader related ?

Answer (score 0):

> My Question is, how to terminate the process without waiting for the
>   loader-threads

simply call `ExitProcess` as usual. this call just terminate process, and of course not wait for loader threads.

> Programs which execute in less than 30 seconds will appear to hang due
>   to ntdll!TppWorkerThreadwaiting for the idle timeout before the
>   process terminates.

this is wrong or poorly worded. this is related to case when process not call `ExitProcess` but simply return from entry point (or terminate self thread).

process exit if:

- [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) called (with no error) - unconditionally
  cause a process to exit. no any user mode cleanup.
- [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) called. however because here exist user mode
  cleanup - it can deadlock under some conditions.
- all threads exit in process. the your quote related exactly to this
  case. if your "single threaded" application just exit from entry
  point without call `ExitProcess` - process exit only in case no other
  threads in process. with parallel loader exist working threads which usually
  live up to 30 seconds if no tasks. as result process will exit not
  immediately. but after 30 seconds. but again - this is only if
  process not call `ExitProcess` direct.

in your case - process (*spawn7.exe* ) :

- or not call `ExitProcess` (in this case it can exit after 30 seconds)
- or deadlock in call `ExitProcess` - in this case need look it
  call-stack and debug it

---

OP say that

> Even if I call `ExitProcess` (withing the 30 seconds while the thread
>   pool ist active) the process is still there with the three threads
>   from ntdll.dll but without my EntryPoint.

this is **false** and can not be. if `ExitProcess` called - first what it do - terminate all of the threads in the process, except the calling thread. or deadlock even before this (in call `RtlLockHeap` for main process heap). so will be:

- or still exist "EntryPoint" thread in process
- or only single thread in process (again your "EntryPoint" thread)

if "still there with the three threads from ntdll.dll but no other" - i can definitely say - `ExitProcess` **not called** (or hooked)

Comment: ExitProcess does not terminate the process. It does things that maybe results in ending all threads and finally the process itself ([see the Remaks section of ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess#remarks)). Even if I call ExitProcess (withing the 30 seconds while the thread pool ist active) the process is still there with the three threads from ntdll.dll but without my EntryPoint. If it where as simple as "simply call ExitProcess as usual" I wouln't have asked.

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt `ExitProcess` **terminate** process or **deadlock**. parallel loader not affect this at all

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt -exist some error in your code or tests. if `ExitProcess` deadlock - will be still visible thread, which call `ExitProcess` and **no other threads**. if *process is still there with the three threads from ntdll.dll but without my EntryPoint.* - this mean that `ExitProcess` **not called**. because first what `ExitProcess` do - **terminate All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread**

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - and i not need see Remarks for exitprocess - i perfect know all this. you not say true. from your description follows that you not call `ExitProcess`. attach say debugger for process and look, are it called.

Comment: As I noted at top if my question, I need to fast fail `if ( !success ) ExitProcess(1);`. So **I do call ExitProcess**. My question is not about how to repair a faulty condition, my question is how to end, exit or terminate that process in case of a faulty condition immediately if ExitProcess doesn't do the job. BTW: The Remarks section in the vendors documentation says: "Therefore, if you do not know the state of all threads in your process, it is better to call TerminateProcess than ExitProcess."

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - you say not true in some place. or you **not call** `ExitProcess` or *process is still there with the three threads from ntdll.dll but without my EntryPoint* - this is false - this can not be if you call `ExitProcess`. so you need better describe situation. and all this not related to parallel loader. `ExitProcess` is normal call. we must call it in most case. only corrupted state of application or bad written 3-rd party dll can cause deadlock in call `ExitProcess`. and now unclear at all - about what you ask ?

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - if you **call** `ExitProcess` but process not exit - it deadlock. will be **single** thread in process. and paste here it call-stack for begin. otherwise - you **not call** `ExitProcess`

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - and *if ExitProcess doesn't do the job.* - `ExitProcess` (if it not hooked, modified) - **never** return. it or terminate process or deadlock.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. My programm is a single threaded GUI-Application. After parsing the command line from PEB it opens files, named pipes or sockets, allocates a console window or attaches to another one, and starts the worker process. On any failure and after the worker is signaled I call ExitProcess and need to get signaled immediately (as my main thread is). Threre is always only one thread visible (and the loaders thread pool) (debugger, Process Explorer). Everything works as expected, except (sometimes) ExitProcess (but my thread is signaled in that case).

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - again - your question/problem absolute unclear. from your latest comment look like bugs in your code. as result it some time deadlock/hungs

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - and you still not want understand - if you call `ExitProcess` - or thread which do this call **deadlock** and not exit (and it will be **single** thread in process). or you **not call** `ExitProcess` at all, your thread **exit**.

Comment: @DanielHammerschmidt - what you need - **debug** your process and exactly describe what happens without errors

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this at the moment, maybe it depends on the day(or night)time.

This situation (three threads in ntdll.dll!TpReleaseWork after exit) not only (sometimes) appears to my program "spawn(7).exe", but also (sometimes) to other (well-known) applications (I can see it in Process Explorer) which I cannot modify. Might be an odd situation in the "new" Feature "Window 10 parallel library loading support in ntdll.dll". Maybe I missed an update, maybe whatever.

Anyway, I need to "fail fast" and because I use the Processes for synchronisation (WaitForSingleObject) I now have two helper funtions.

ExitProcessNow to "kill" myself and WaitForProcessOrMainThread to wait for the target process (or its main thread) recently created with a call to CreateProcess.

```c
VOID
__stdcall
ExitProcessNow( UINT uExitCode )
{
  if ( TerminateProcess( GetCurrentProcess(),
                         uExitCode ) )
    ExitThread( uExitCode );
  else
    ExitProcess( uExitCode );
}

VOID
__stdcall
WaitForProcessOrMainThread( PPROCESS_INFORMATION pProcessInformation,
                            BOOL fWaitForThread )
{
  if ( !fWaitForThread )
    WaitForSingleObject( pProcessInformation->hProcess, INFINITE );
  else
  {
    DWORD ExitCode = 0;
    WaitForSingleObject( pProcessInformation->hThread, INFINITE );
    GetExitCodeThread( pProcessInformation->hThread, &ExitCode );
    TerminateProcess( pProcessInformation->hProcess, ExitCode );
  }
  CloseHandle( pProcessInformation->hThread );
  CloseHandle( pProcessInformation->hProcess );
  pProcessInformation->hThread = NULL;
  pProcessInformation->hProcess = NULL;
}
```

BTW:

> Interestingly, Windows 10 contains a default entry for chrome.exe with MaxLoaderThreads set to 1 to disable parallel loading.
>   *[Windows 10 Parallel Loading Breakdown](https://threatvector.cylance.com/en_us/home/windows-10-parallel-loading-breakdown.html)*

There might be a reason for it. ;-)

Comment: you go in wrong direction. parallel loader here unrelated. exist some error in your code, when you not call `ExitProcess` or something else. chrome use *Untrusted Mandatory Level* for process token and other strong restrictions. with such token - impossible load any dll. so working loader threads will fail in chrome. because this it and disabled. only first chrome thread start on *Low Mandatory Level* and less restricted token. only this thread can load dlls and initialize process. then it drop token

Comment: all your posted here code - not resolve error in your code, but try hide it. this is wrong way. if thread call `ExitProcess` - it or really terminate process or deadlock. in second case `WaitForSingleObject( pProcessInformation->hThread, INFINITE );` - not help you. you will be wait infinite. from other side - if `pProcessInformation->hThread` exit but process not exit- this 100% mean - it **not call** `ExitProcess`. `TerminateProcess( GetCurrentProcess(),
                         uExitCode ) )` - never return - so any code after it senseless. all what you try todo wrong

Comment: I don't know what try to tell me. I told you, there are other programs out there with this behavior. I told - in my question - that TerminateProcess( -1, 0 ) works in situations where ExitProcess( 0 ) does not. I told you, I don't care about the situation, I just need do terminate in case of any error and I need to detect if others (or its main thread) terminate. My posted code does exactly what it shold do: it detects when the callee or its main thread terminates and it terminates its process immediately in case of an error.

Comment: BTW: I do not know what I have to "spawn". I dont care. I have to make sure it's running and have to restart it if it fails.

Comment: *I told you, there are other programs out there with this behavior* - this is wrong - other programs just exit when need to exit. *I told - in my question - that TerminateProcess( -1, 0 ) works in situations where ExitProcess( 0 ) does not*  - and i told you that you **mistake**. you **not call** `ExitProcess`. *My posted code* - wrong

Comment: I guess, you're right. I guess, you know exactly every version and build of Windows in every possible environmet and how it behaves in every configuration. I guess, watchdogs - either hardare or software - are not neccessary. I guess nobody has ever seen a BSOD. I guess you know exactly what I see or have seen when I inspect processes on my computer. So I have to thank you again for your time.